# Creating an extension of WebView in Xamarin.Froms to display gifs. I cannot load the image on Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, gif

iOS works as expected. I have tried adding the .gif to the assets folder too (setting the BaseUrl to "file:///android_asset") with no luck. Any ideas?

```
imageHtml = "<center><body bgcolor =\""
                        + GetBackgroundColorHex()
                        + "\""
                        + heightAndWidth
                        + ">"
                        + (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(imageFileName)
                            ? "<img src=\"" 
                            + imageFileName 
                            + "\""
                            + heightAndWidth
                            + "/>"
                            : "&nbsp;")
                        + "</body></center>";

            HtmlWebViewSource source = new HtmlWebViewSource()
            {
                Html = imageHtml
            };

            if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(imageFileName))
            {
                source.BaseUrl = "file:///android_res/drawable/";
            }

            Source = source;
```

Here's the error I get in output:

```
12-11 02:08:00.256 E/AndroidProtocolHandler(12895): Unable to open resource URL: file:///android_res/drawable/Loading.gif
12-11 02:08:00.256 E/AndroidProtocolHandler(12895): java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: Loading
12-11 02:08:00.256 E/AndroidProtocolHandler(12895):     at java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:1549)
12-11 02:08:00.256 E/AndroidProtocolHandler(12895):     at org.chromium.android_webview.AndroidProtocolHandler.getFieldId(AndroidProtocolHandler.java:40)
12-11 02:08:00.256 E/AndroidProtocolHandler(12895):     at org.chromium.android_webview.AndroidProtocolHandler.openResource(AndroidProtocolHandler.java:54)
12-11 02:08:00.256 E/AndroidProtocolHandler(12895):     at org.chromium.android_webview.AndroidProtocolHandler.open(AndroidProtocolHandler.java:10)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can load `Android.Webkit.WebView` content via assets, not drawables.

Here is the `Xamarin.Android` code to parse the image to get its width/height to insure the aspect ratio is preserved and display it from the Asset folder:

#### WebView Gif Viewer:

```
var src = "out.gif";
var backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
int imageWidth;
int imageHeight;
using (var stream = Assets.Open(src))
using (var options = new BitmapFactory.Options { InJustDecodeBounds = true })
{
    await BitmapFactory.DecodeStreamAsync(stream, null, options);
    imageWidth = options.OutWidth;
    imageHeight = options.OutHeight;
}
var html = $"<body bgcolor={backgroundColor};\"><img src=\"{src}\" alt=\"A Gif file\" width=\"{imageWidth}\" height=\"{imageHeight}\" style=\"width: 100%; height: auto;\"/></body>";
webView.Settings.AllowFileAccessFromFileURLs = true;
webView.LoadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", html, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

[image]

#### Via Xamarin.Forms `WebView`:

```
var src = "image.gif";
var backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
int imageWidth = 300;
int imageHeight = 200;
var html = $"<body bgcolor={backgroundColor};\"><img src=\"{src}\" alt=\"A Gif file\" width=\"{imageWidth}\" height=\"{imageHeight}\" style=\"width: 100%; height: auto;\"/></body>";
webView.Source = new HtmlWebViewSource
{
    Html = html
};
```

Note: `image.gif` is in the Android Assets (`AndroidResource`) folder and iOS Resource folder (`BundleResource`)

Comment: Currently all my code is PCL for Forms. This looks like I'll need a custom renderer for Android. I can't seem to find out to set AllowFileAccessFromFileURLs in Forms. Is it possible to do in PCL?

Comment: @GarrettDanielDeMeyer When you said you were creating a extension of WebView, I assumed custom platform renderer. I just went and looked at the Forms  WebViewRenderer source and they are setting the WebView client to be the ChromeClient, it will work fine without a custom renderer...  see my update...

Answer (score 0):

Save your GIF file at Assets folder. Here "loading.gif" is the filename.

```
WebView webView=new WebView
{
      Source = new HtmlWebViewSource
      {
          Html = $"<body\"><img src=\"loading.gif\"/></body>"
      }
};
Content = webView;
```

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin.Forms now **supports .GIF**, from version 4.4-pre3 and up on iOS, Android and UWP. Before using, first add the .GIF to the platforms projects, or as an embedded resource in the shared project and then use it like a regular image.The API on the Image control has been extended with the **IsAnimationPlaying** bindable property.

For e.g., loader.gif is added in all platform projects, then below code make it animating.

```
<Image Source="loader" IsAnimationPlaying="True" WidthRequest="36" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"></Image>
```