# How to display gif image in Xamarin form?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a gif image and I want to display it on screen app. I use library FFImageLoading to load gif image, but I can't display it in xamarin.forms 3.1. 
I don't know whether other library support load gif image?
Please help me!
Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47750202/4984832

Answer (score 13, accepted):

FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms supports gif images. I'm having no problem displaying the gif using FFImageLoading.

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"  x:Class="MyApp.AnimationView" 
         xmlns:ffimageloading="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms">

    <ffimageloading:SvgCachedImage HeightRequest="30" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" Aspect="AspectFill" x:Name="imageWave" Source="Wave.gif" Margin="0"/>

</ContentView>
```

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Thanks you! I add wrong path "Source" image... I fixed it.

Comment: In UWP Gif is not working for me, working fine on android and ios. Is there anything more added to UWP?

Comment: Those links content more datails: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/365397/gif-file-is-not-loading-the-xamarin-forms and https://support.syncfusion.com/kb/article/10671/how-to-enable-ffimageloading-transformation-in-xamarin-forms-listview-sflistview