# How to rapid load image gif use FFImageLoading in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Size of my Gif Image is 2 MB. I use library FFImageLoading of Xamarin Forms to load it. But time load is more than 7 second. 
How to rapid load gif image?

I am currently using path image:

```
<ffimageloading:SvgCachedImage HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Aspect="AspectFill" x:Name="Gif" Source="{Binding image}" Margin="0"/>
```

And Name of Gif image is:

```
image = "GifImage.gif"
```

User can't wait load image gif.
So, please support me that how to rapid load gif image on Xamarin Forms.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use WebView on Xamarin Forms:

At file `.xaml` add source:

```
            <WebView HorizontalOptions="Center"
                 VerticalOptions="Center"
                 HeightRequest="{Binding HeightImage}"
                 WidthRequest="{Binding WidthImage}"
                 Source="{Binding LinkImageGif}" />
```

At file `.cs` add source:

```
            int imageHeight = HeightImage;
            int imageWidth = WidthImage;

            var source = new HtmlWebViewSource
            {
                Html = $"<body\"><img src=\"{_srcImage}\" alt=\"A Gif file\" width=\"{imageWidth}\" height=\"{imageHeight}\" style=\"width: 100%; height: auto;\"/></body>",
                BaseUrl = DependencyService.Get<IBaseUrl>().Get()
            };
```

Because `BaseUrl` of Android and iOS is difference. So, use Share Project, create a dependecy.

First, create a `Interface`:

```
namespace abcxyz
{
    public interface IBaseUrl { string Get(); }
}
```

At dependecy of Android, add code:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(BaseUrlAndroid))]
namespace abcxyz
{
    public class BaseUrlAndroid : IBaseUrl
    {
        public string Get() => "file:///android_asset/";
    }
}
```

(Gif image will be add at folder: Assets of `AndroidResource`)

At dependecy of iOS, add code:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(BaseUrlOniOs))]
namespace abcxyz
{
    public class BaseUrlOniOs : IBaseUrl
    {
        public string Get()
        {
            return NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath;
        }
    }
}
```

(Gif image will be add at folder: `Resource` (`BundleResource`) of iOS)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `WebView` that load rapid Gif Image. 
Use WebView don't need set up any library.
I used it that replace library `FFImageLoading`.
It create a .html contain Gif Image, so load very fast.
You can reference use it at:
[WebView Gif Viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47748780/creating-an-extension-of-webview-in-xamarin-froms-to-display-gifs-i-cannot-load)